# How can I change the SEF URL to non-SEF URL in Joomla for single view?

Tags: php, joomla, sef

I am creating an API type plugin, which fetches activity stream from easysocial.
But I got SEF URL in the activity stream, I want the NON-SEF URL in case SEF is on in Joomla configuration.

Please tell me how can I do this, programmatically.

I tried to override the Joomla config setting in my plugins, but it won't work as given below.

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$sef = $config->set('sef', 0);
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If it did, then please mark it as such so other people who search for this issue can see it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make a special .htaccess rule for that

Find this section:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

And add this line above it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php?option=com_something&var=something
```

Where you change the URL to be the nonSEF url you do not want parsed.

I have not verified this. Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: Hi, Is there any other way, so i can change it for specific page or view.

Comment: You can do that with the above? Just add more lines.